# Get closet device

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there any way to get the device that is closest to the phone, or a list of available devices sorted by closest devices with [BuetoothLE Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-le)?

Something like:

```
...

ble: BluetoothLE
...
const params: ScanParams = {
  services: [],
  allowDuplicates: false,
  scanMode: this.ble.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY, //Something to do here maybe?
  matchMode: this.ble.MATCH_NUM_MAX_ADVERTISEMENT,
  matchNum: this.ble.MATCH_NUM_ONE_ADVERTISEMENT
};
this.ble.startScan(params).subscribe(device=>{
   //Something to do here maybe?
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do is use the signal strength (RSSI). But the signal strength can be affected by obstacles and not just distance.